# Java : Run a new JVM and send all new requests for a particular jar to that JVM

Tags: java, spring, jar, jvm, multiprocessing

So I have a jar, say "A.jar". I have a Spring MVC project from whose controller I will be calling this jar to execute a piece of code based on some parameters.

I wanted the jar call to be "**out of process**" so that it has ample amount of resources and even in case of failure of the first JVM, this keeps on running.

Currently, I am using a **ProcessBuilder** and the controller generates a new process for each request. My requirement is that I want one separate process/JVM for the jar execution, to which I can pass parameters. In case of multiple requests, they should line up as a queue and processing should be done accordingly.

ProcessBuilder Code:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\javaAPI.jar", argList[0]);
        try {
           // start the subprocess
           Process p = pb.start();
           p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

P.S. Still in college, first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you are using `ProcessBuilder`, show your code here and state clearly what error you have encountered. This is what this site is set up for. If you have no idea how to do your assignment and ask here, this is NOT what this site is set up for.

Comment: One, no errors. Two, not an assignment, personal work. Three, try being subtle, it would help

Comment: Rather than starting the process right away you could queue them using some implementation  of `BlockingQueue`. And a separate consumer read these objects and start the process.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Trying your approach, will hopefully solve my purpose

Comment: Great. If possible do update if it worked.